# Increment or reset the count everytime an array is generated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So here's the scenario. The current output I'm getting is an array of objects like this

```
[{ 
    usertype: '2',
    username: 'Pawar',
    calls: [],
    time: 0 },
  { 
    usertype: '2',
    username: 'Pallavi',
    calls: [ [Object] ],
    time: 1 }]
```

As you can see there's a calls array inside the objects. Sometimes the calls array is empty and sometimes it contains values. So if the calls array is empty then the value of the time key should be 0 sp this part is working fine. But if the calls object is not empty then the time should be incremented by 1. Suppose I let the code to execute 10 times, if the calls array is not empty for those 10 iterations then the time should be displayed as 10 and if in any iteration the calls array is empty the time will be 0 and then keep on incrementing until the calls array comes as empty.

As a new array of objects is being generated every time I execute the code, so my time doesn't get incremented. I have declared a time variable with a value of 0 and when the calls array is not empty I have added code to set time = time+1. But here the time remains 1 everytime the calls array is not empty.

The expected output I want is as shown below :

If the code is executed for say 10 seconds and the calls array is not empty then the expected output is :

```
[{ 
    usertype: '2',
    username: 'Pawar',
    calls: [],
    time: 0 },
  { 
    usertype: '2',
    username: 'Pallavi',
    calls: [ [Object] ],
    time: 10 }]
```

Please help me to figure out how to go about this problem

Comment: `But if the calls object is not empty then the time should be incremented by 1` => do you refer to the calls object of the element that has just been generated? Whose `time` field do you increment? Of all the elements or just the current one?

Comment: In my array all the objects contain calls array. So in whichever object the calls array is empty the time should be 0 and if not empty the time should be incremented by 1 until it comes as empty. There are many objects in my array. The time will be incremented or set to 0 accordingly based on the calls array of each object for each object

Comment: The objects update themselves? An object that has an empty calls array might receive an element?

Comment: Yes the calls array in each object get's updated everytime depending on the data being sent from the server in every iteration. Calls array remain's empty for sometime and may receive data anytime depending on the server

Comment: Are the objects replaced entirely or is the same reference that is updated?

Comment: They are replaced completely in every iteration. The main array is regenerated everytime the code executes. The entire array of objects is regenerated

Comment: Why is a new array being generated instead of updating the old array? I think you need to fix that problem. Otherwise, there's no easy way to persist any information.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right. I'll work on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to keep a copy of the old array (or objects) before replacing them entirely. You'd have to update the new ones based on the properties of the old ones and then replacing the array/objects.

I made a simulation in the snippet below. I'm not saying it is the best solution, but it is one (without any automatic mechanism to update them).

```js
var workingArray = [{
  usertype: '2',
  username: 'A',
  calls: [],
  time: 0
}, {
  usertype: '2',
  username: 'B',
  calls: [],
  time: 10
}, {
  usertype: '2',
  username: 'C',
  calls: [],
  time: 10
}];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getNewData() {
  let usersNames = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  let newData = [];
  
  usersNames.forEach(usersName => {
    let callsNumber = getRandomInt(0, 3);
    let calls = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < callsNumber; ++i) {
      calls.push(new Object());
    }
    
    newData.push({
      usertype: '2',
      username: usersName,
      calls: calls,
      time: 0
    });
  });
  
  return newData;
}

function simulate() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // get new data but don't overwrite
    let newData = getNewData();
    
    // update new data based on old data
    newData.forEach(newUser => {
      // search old user that matches this one
      let oldUser = null;
      
      for (let i = 0; i < workingArray.length; ++i) {
        if (workingArray[i].username === newUser.username &&
            workingArray[i].usertype === newUser.usertype) {
            
            if (!newUser.calls.length) {
              newUser.time = workingArray[i].time + 1;
              console.log(newUser.username + " " + (newUser.time - 1) + " => " + newUser.time);
              
            } else {
             console.log(newUser.username + " => no changes (" + newUser.time + ")");
            }
            
            workingArray[i] = newUser;
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    
    simulate();
  }, 1000);
}

simulate();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Adi for your efforts to help me out. I implemented your code and it's working for me